# How do I get the nested callback results inside another file in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

So my API code is here in this file api.js

api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo;
var lib = new Vimeo('dfdfdfdfdfdfd', 'WDIt+kEVudfghjklkjhgfdfghjkjhgfMaG9X3Ml', 'jhjhjhjhjhjhgfg');

var app = express();

app.listen(9999);
var results =
    app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
        lib.request(/*options*/{
            // This is the path for the videos contained within the staff picks channels
            path: '/channels/staffpicks/videos',
            // This adds the parameters to request page two, and 10 items per page
            query: {
                page: 1,
                per_page: 2,
                fields: 'uri,name,description,duration,created_time,modified_time'
            }
        }, /*callback*/function (error, body, status_code, headers) {
            if (error) {
                // console.log('error -------------------------------------');
                // console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(body); //how to get this in server.js
                res.send(JSON.stringify(body['data'])); //how to get this in server.js

            }
        });

    });
console.log("Server is listening");
module.exports = {
    results: results,
}
```

server.js

```
var api = require('./vimeo/api.js');
var a  =  api.results;
//blah blah
 console.log(a);// how to get calback data from api.js function here?
 }));
```

How do I access console.log values in server.js that are available in api.js?

Comment: can you post the whole content of server.js?

Comment: Thats my whole content in server.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `app.get()` call in a `Promise` like this:

```
var results =
  new Promise(resolve => app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    ...
  }));
```

And then you replace `console.log(body);` with:

```
resolve(body);
```

Now `results` is a `Promise` so it will be available in `server.js` once it resolves:

```
var api = require('./vimeo/api.js');
api.results.then((a) => {
  console.log(a);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both `api.js` and `server.js` are being run on the same process you can add a function to `server.js` to intercept anything being written to `process.stdout` by wrapping it in a function that can call a hook function, that hook function needs to return the original argument being written to `process.stdout` so it doesn't break `console.log()`

One example of how I use this is to intercept anything being logged to the console and writing it to a file. It doesn't require any further code in any files that you want to intercept the `console.log()` for, it will work across anything writing to `process.stdout` running on the same process.

```
function hookStdOut(hook => {
  process.stdout.write = (write => {
    return (...args) => {
      args[0] = hook[args[0]]
      write.apply(process.stdout, args)
    }
  })(process.stdout.write)
}

hookStdOut(chunk => {
  // access whatever was being written to stdout and process
  // you cannot use console.log within this function 
  // because it will result in an infinite loop since 
  //console.log writes to process.stdout

  // return the chunk so it will be written back to process.stdout
  return chunk
})
```

Comment: I would prefer express way. Sorry for not tagging as express initially.

Comment: @Mike what do you mean "express way"?

Answer (score 0):

you can export a function in server.js and pass the async data from api.js as soon as are available.

server.js

```
var api = require('./vimeo/api.js');
module.exports = function(data){
  var a  =  api.results;
 console.log(data); //your async data

}
```

and inside api.js

```
//after you receive the data
else {
  var serverModule = require('./server');
  serverModule(data); //call the method
  res.send(JSON.stringify(body['data']));
}
```